# Find the area of a tangential trapezium

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Given a tangential trapezium in which the lengths of the legs are $4cm$ and $5cm$ and the sum of the angles on the longer base is $120°$, find the area.

[image: Illustration]

Let $AD=5cm$, $BC=4cm$.
From the fact that the given trapezium is a tangential one, it follows that
$AB+CD=BC+AD=9cm$.

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Is a "tangential trapezium" defined as a trapezium having an inscribed circle ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, tangential trapezium means a trapezium that can be circumscribed in a circle. [See here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_trapezoid) for reference.

Comment: I started to type yesterday some answer, a geometric solution, wanted to add only the picture. The picture is done. But now the question is closed, as i detected while copy+pasting the picture. Please add the needed information to the question, so that it meets the MSE standard, this is done by adding more "context". (For instance adding the source, the level, some real own tries to solve the problem. The same problem will be faced by the next post...) If the question becomes visible again, after unclosing, i will simply commit the already typed answer by a click, please give me a message here

Comment: @Unknown The question is unfortunately "not generously" matching the "rules" in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question, it is hard to find the question, we have a cited problem without source, the progress shown is not really a progress (given that the solution is "not so trivial", i have the number, the sides of the trapezium, the height... anyway, the "work" is at some other place), the picture is rather a picture of a general trapezium. I'm missing e.g. the question in the text, the construction of the trapezium (which imminently leads to solution) etc

Comment: @Unknown ... and then there will be the next post, with the same problems... People with much higher reputation than mine have voted to close... And i can only edit the question, there is no unclose-button for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that the area of the trapezium is $\frac12\cdot(AB+CD)\cdot h$. Since you found $AB+CD=9$, it is enough to solve for $h$. Let $DE\perp AB$ and $CF\perp AB$. Now $DE=CF=h$ and $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle CBF$ are two right triangles. Let $\angle DAE=\theta$, then $\angle CBF=120-\theta$. Now $\sin\theta=\frac{h}{AD}=\frac h5$ and $\sin(120-\theta)=\frac h4$. Now you have the equation $4\sin(120-\theta)=5\sin\theta$. Now solve for $\theta$ and $h$ simultaneously. Use the formula $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A$.